# how to unit test a form that has state and method from a custom hook with jest

Tags: reactjs, forms, unit-testing, redux, react-redux

this is the test for the above component

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import AddDeviceWrapper from "../AddDeviceWrapper";

describe("Form", () => {
  test("Handles input changes with saveDeviceChange when typing or editing an value", () => {
    const handleFormInputMock = jest.fn();
    const store = configureStore();

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AddDeviceWrapper
          system_name={""}
          type={""}
          hdd_capacity={""}
          saveDeviceChange={handleFormInputMock}
        />
      </Provider>
    );

    const systemName = screen.getByLabelText("System Name *");
    const type = screen.getByLabelText("Type *");
    const hddCapacity = screen.getByLabelText("HDD Capacity (GB) *");

    userEvent.type(systemName, "yoda_mac");
    expect(handleFormInputMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(handleFormInputMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("systemName", "yoda_mac");

    userEvent.type(type, "MAC");
    expect(handleFormInputMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("type", "MAC");

    userEvent.type(hddCapacity, { target: { value: 500 } });
    expect(handleFormInputMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("hddCapacity", 500);
  });
});
```

The test is failed with the following messages

> react-scripts test
> FAIL  src/components/*tests*/AddDeviceWrapper.test.js
> Form
> ✕ Handles input changes with saveDeviceChange when typing or editing an value (32 ms)

● Form › Handles input changes with saveDeviceChange when typing or editing an value

```
TypeError: store.getState is not a function

  11 |     const store = configureStore();
  12 |
> 13 |     render(
     |     ^
  14 |       <Provider store={store}>
  15 |         <AddDeviceWrapper
  16 |           system_name={""}
```

console.error
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`.
at Provider (/Users/yongyili/Documents/coding-assessments/devices-clientapp/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:21:20)

```
  12 |
  13 |     render(
> 14 |       <Provider store={store}>
     |       ^
  15 |         <AddDeviceWrapper
  16 |           system_name={""}
  17 |           type={""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `configureStore()` function from `redux-mock-store` returns a creator function. This is in case you want to add middleware to it. To get your mock store, you should do this:

```
const createStore = configureStore();
const mockStore = createStore();
```

Then you can use `mockStore` as normal in the rest of your tests.